# Escaping special character in string in C#

Tags: c#

Need your help in below.

I have code where I am checking that a particular row exists in datatable or not; if row doesn't exist then I add that row to datatable. This is working fine however failing when row value contains special char link `'` (single quote).

Below is the code:

```
string lastName = dgRow.Cells[2].Text.Replace("amp;", "");
DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("LastName='" + lastName + "'"); //check whether row is available in datatable or not

if (dr.Length <= 0)// Condition to check if row is there in data table
{
    dt.Rows.Add();
    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["FirstName"] = dgRow.Cells[1].Text;
    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["LastName"] = dgRow.Cells[2].Text;
    dt.AcceptChanges();
}
return dt; //Return modified data table to calling function.
```

This code fails when LastName contains single quotes.

I need a solution where I am not removing quotes from last name.

Thanks

Comment: this code is running On the Web Form?

Comment: you mean this code dgRow.Cells[2].Text contains quotes?

Comment: you can replace '(single quote) with ''(double)...

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `dt.Select()` in the first place, I'd strongly suggest using LINQ. It avoids the whole "embedding queries in strings" problem which is so ghastly and reminiscent of SQL injection attacks.

So:

```
var lastNameToFind = dgRow.Cells[2].Text.Replace("&amp;", "");
var matched = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(dr => dr["LastName"].Equals(lastNameToFind))
                .Any();

if (matched)
{
    DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
    dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
    newRow["FirstName"] = dgRow.Cells[1].Text;
    newRow["LastName"] = dgRow.Cells[2].Text;
    dt.AcceptChanges();
}
```

Comment: I didn't want to suggest this as an edit in case I've just misunderstood.  I implemented your code above but got an error that 'dr' was undefined.  After some reading to improve my understanding of LINQ (so thanks for providing a prompt to do so!) I changed it to .Where(dr => dr["LastName"].Equals(lastNameToFind)) and this solved it.  Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("LastName='" + dgRow.Cells[2].Text.Replace
("amp;", "")+ "'");
```

to this:

```
DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("LastName='" + dgRow.Cells[2].Text.Replace
("amp;", "").Replace("\'", "\'\'") + "'");
```

*(untested)*

Comment: Better implementation (as mentioned by @Rawling) in [Correct way to escape characters in a DataTable Filter Expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386122/correct-way-to-escape-characters-in-a-datatable-filter-expression)

Comment: Thanks, this is working however its failing in newRow["LastName"] = dgRow.Cells[2].Text; also in my datatable only single quote should go

Answer (score 0):

You can replace **Single quote** with **Double Quote** :

```
Dim LastName As String = Replace(txtLastName.Text, "'", "''")
```

but it is not good practice...

check this out : [Replacing apostrophe in asp.net to prevent SQL error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476445/replacing-apostrophe-in-asp-net-to-prevent-sql-error)